# AWS CDK PatchBaseline

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create a patch baseline for patching Linux hosts, however i keep getting the same error again and again. Please help, i just don't see the problem, I've checked some code in TS that people have used, but no progress yet.

**PatchBaselineLinux 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'approvalRules.patchRules' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null. (Service: AmazonSSM; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;**

```
    baseline1 = CfnPatchBaseline(self, "PatchBaselineLinux",
                                 name="TestPatchBaseline_Linux",
                                 operating_system="AMAZON_LINUX_2",
                                 description="TestPatchBaseline for Linux updates, Amazon_Linux_2 distr.",
                                 approved_patches_enable_non_security=True,
                                 approval_rules={"patch_rules": [
                                     {
                                         "enable_non_security": True,
                                         "approve_after_days": 1,
                                         "approve_until_date": "2021-02-09",
                                         "compliance_level": "CRITICAL",
                                         "patch_filter_group": {"patch_filters": [
                                             {"key": "PRODUCT", "values": ['AmazonLinux2', 'AmazonLinux2.0']},
                                             {"key": "CLASSIFICATION",
                                              "values": ["Security", "Bugfix", "Enhancement", "Recommended"]},
                                             {"key": "SEVERITY",
                                              "values": ["Critical", "Important", "Medium", "Low"]}]}
                                     }
                                 ]
                                 },
                                 patch_groups=["AWS-Linux-2-Test"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest splitting out your approval rules.  approval_rules is expecting RuleGroupProperty. You have a json string.  Check the following link for details:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ssm/CfnPatchBaseline.html#aws_cdk.aws_ssm.CfnPatchBaseline.RuleGroupProperty

The following should work. Make sure to check all the properties, I didn't include everything you had.

```
def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

    amazon_linux2_product_patch_filter = ssm.CfnPatchBaseline.PatchFilterProperty(key='PRODUCT',
                                                                                  values=['AmazonLinux2',
                                                                                          'AmazonLinux2.0'])

    amazon_linux2_classification_patch_filter = ssm.CfnPatchBaseline.PatchFilterProperty(key='CLASSIFICATION',
                                                                                         values=['Security',
                                                                                                 'Bugfix',
                                                                                                 'Enhancement',
                                                                                                 'Recommended'])

    amazon_linux2_severity_patch_filter = ssm.CfnPatchBaseline.PatchFilterProperty(key='SEVERITY',
                                                                                   values=['Critical',
                                                                                           'Important',
                                                                                           'Medium',
                                                                                           'Low'])

    patch_baseline_patch_filter_group = ssm.CfnPatchBaseline.PatchFilterGroupProperty(
        patch_filters=[amazon_linux2_product_patch_filter,
                       amazon_linux2_classification_patch_filter,
                       amazon_linux2_severity_patch_filter])

    patch_baseline_rule = ssm.CfnPatchBaseline.RuleProperty(approve_after_days=0,
                                                            compliance_level='CRITICAL',
                                                            enable_non_security=True,
                                                            patch_filter_group=patch_baseline_patch_filter_group
                                                            )

    patch_baseline_rule_group = ssm.CfnPatchBaseline.RuleGroupProperty(patch_rules=[patch_baseline_rule])

    patch_baseline = ssm.CfnPatchBaseline(self, 'rPatchBaseline',
                                          name=f'TestPatchBaseline_Linux',
                                          description='TestPatchBaseline for Linux updates, Amazon_Linux_2 distr.',
                                          operating_system='AMAZON_LINUX_2',
                                          approved_patches_enable_non_security=True,
                                          patch_groups=['AWS-Linux-2-Test'],
                                          approval_rules=patch_baseline_rule_group,
                                          )
```