# AWS CDK PatchBaseline - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK, library [@aws-cdk/aws-ssm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ssm-readme.html) and TypeScript to create PatchBaseline. I can create Patch baseline but I am not able to define any approvalRules. I have found similar thread where [Alex Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276446/alex-nelson) creates approvalRules as an object using RuleProperty, he does it in Python but I am not able to replicate this procedure in TypeScript. For some reason I cannot use RuleProperty in TypeScript like Alex did in Python, more in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65994414/aws-cdk-patchbaseline).

This line of code gives me an error that Property 'RuleProperty' does not exist on type 'typeof CfnPatchBaseline'.

```
const patch_baseline_rule = new ssm.CfnPatchBaseline.RuleProperty();
```

I spent hours going through the CDK documentation but I did not find there anything usefull related to my issue. In case of [RuleGroupProperty](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ssm.CfnPatchBaseline.RuleGroupProperty.html) the documentation does not provide any examples at all.

My question is, how to type following code (Python) in TypeScript?

```
patch_baseline_rule = ssm.CfnPatchBaseline.RuleProperty(approve_after_days=0,
                                                        compliance_level='CRITICAL',
                                                        enable_non_security=True,
                                                        patch_filter_group=patch_baseline_patch_filter_group
                                                        )

patch_baseline_rule_group = ssm.CfnPatchBaseline.RuleGroupProperty(patch_rules=[patch_baseline_rule])

patch_baseline = ssm.CfnPatchBaseline(self, 'rPatchBaseline',
                                      name=f'TestPatchBaseline_Linux',
                                      description='TestPatchBaseline for Linux updates, Amazon_Linux_2 distr.',
                                      operating_system='AMAZON_LINUX_2',
                                      approved_patches_enable_non_security=True,
                                      patch_groups=['AWS-Linux-2-Test'],
                                      approval_rules=patch_baseline_rule_group,
                                      )
```

Comment: For reference, will you please link Alex's post in your question?

Comment: @Hcaertnit Sure, link added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things like `RuleProperty` and `RuleGroupProperty` are classes in Python, but in TypeScript, they're just interfaces, so you don't directly create them.  Instead, you create normal JavaScript objects, and your editor or the CDK itself will tell you if you're creating the object incorrectly.

In case you're not aware, it's also common practice to use `camelCase` names in JavaScript, rather than `snake_case` like you'd do in Python.  Because of that, you'll need to specify property names as `camelCase` as well.

Note: the `this` keyword is used in JavaScript/TypeScript, while it's `self` in Python.

Here is the TypeScript equivalent of your Python code:

```js
import ssm from "@aws-cdk/aws-ssm";

const patchBaselineRule = {
  approveAfterDays: 0,
  complianceLevel: "CRITICAL",
  enableNonSecurity: true,
  patchFilterGroup: patch_baseline_patch_filter_group,
};

const patchBaselineRuleGroup = {
  patchRules: [patchBaselineRule],
};

const patchBaseline = new ssm.CfnPatchBaseline(this, "rPatchBaseline", {
  name: "TestPatchBaseline_Linux",
  description: "TestPatchBaseline for Linux updates, Amazon_Linux_2 distr.",
  operatingSystem: "AMAZON_LINUX_2",
  approvedPatchesEnableNonSecurity: true,
  patchGroups: ["AWS-Linux-2-Test"],
  approvalRules: patchBaselineRuleGroup,
});
```

Comment: I didn't realize that you are able to create interface as normal JS object, this explains a lot to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, it can be rather confusing.  Did you know that you can use `dict`s in Python for parameters _or_ a classes?  e.g. you used `RuleProperty` and `RuleGroupProperty` in your Python code, but you actually could've just made them be `dict`s (though you wouldn't get intellisense) :D