# AWS CDK CfnPatchBaseline, Approval rules for Microsoft applications

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-ssm

### My goal is to deploy CfnPatchBaseline which specifies approval rule for SQL on Windows Server using CDK and TypeScript.

I have successfully created CfnPatchBaseline for Windows server instances using CDK. This means that I am able to control updates on the OS layer.

**Now I would like to control updates on the application layer as well.**

In the AWS console (browser interface) I am able to specify **Approval rules for Microsoft applications** in the patch baseline and it works just fine. The problem is that I do not know how to replicate the same thing in the CDK.

I have tried to create new patchFilter with **PRODUCT_FAMILY** as a key and **SQL Server** as value

```
const patchFilterProductWindowsServerSQL = {
            key: 'PRODUCT_FAMILY',
            values: ['SQL Server']
        };
```

but I have received following error: *"Invalid Filter Value: SQL Server for Key: PRODUCT_FAMILY, valid values are: WINDOWS"*.

Code I have used for creating my Windows Server patch baseline.

```
const patchFilterProductWindowsServer = {
            key: 'PRODUCT',
            values: ['WindowsServer2019']
        };

const patchFilterClassificationWindowsServer = {
            key: 'CLASSIFICATION',
            values: [
                'CriticalUpdates',
                'SecurityUpdates',
                'Updates'
            ]
        };

const patchFilterSeverityWindowsServer = {
            key: 'MSRC_SEVERITY',
            values: [
                'Critical',
                'Important'
            ]
        };

const patchBaselinePatchFilterGroupWindowsServer = {
            patchFilters: [
                patchFilterProductWindowsServer,
                patchFilterClassificationWindowsServer,
                patchFilterSeverityWindowsServer
            ]
        };

const patchBaselineRuleHighWindowsServer = {
            approveAfterDays: 7,
            complianceLevel: "HIGH",
            patchFilterGroup: patchBaselinePatchFilterGroupWindowsServer
        };

const patchBaselineRuleGroupWindowsServer = {
            patchRules: [
                patchBaselineRuleHighWindowsServer
            ]
        };

const patchBaselineWinServer = new ssm.CfnPatchBaseline(this, "Windows-Server-CritImp-CDK", {
            name: "Windows-Server-CritImp-CDK",
            operatingSystem: "WINDOWS",
            patchGroups: "Windows-Server-CDK",
            approvalRules: patchBaselineRuleGroupWindowsServer
        });
```

Screenshot from AWS console of my approval rule, which I can create using CDK, and **Approval rules for Microsoft applications**, which I am not able to create using CDK. Rules in the screenshots were created manually from the console.
[image]

This thread is an follow up to this one - [AWS CDK PatchBaseline - TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440776/aws-cdk-patchbaseline-typescript)

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of your Patch Baseline configuration from the console?  It will help me to create the PB for myself and investigate.

Comment: @Hcaertnit Sure, I have updated my post with the screenshot showing my Approval rule (created with CDK) and the desired SQL rule in the Approval rules for Microsoft applications section. Thank you very much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to explicitly specify the PATCH_SET as "APPLICATION" as well. Following code does the job.

```
const patchBaselineRuleHighWindowsServerSQL = {
            approveAfterDays: 7,
            complianceLevel: "HIGH",
            patchFilterGroup: {
                patchFilters: [
                    {
                        key: 'PRODUCT_FAMILY',
                        values: ['SQL Server']
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'PATCH_SET',
                        values: ['APPLICATION']
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'MSRC_SEVERITY',
                        values: [
                            'Critical',
                            'Important'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'CLASSIFICATION',
                        values: [
                            'CriticalUpdates',
                            'SecurityUpdates'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'PRODUCT',
                        values: ['*']
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
```